# Создание общих изменяемых данных для всех классов активити

Tags: android, activity

У меня следующая проблема: Мне нужно передать булевский массив из MainActivity в другие классы и иметь возможность его там редактировать. Уже отредактированные данные должны быть доступны тоже всем остальным классам, т.к. он влияет на отображение некоторых элементов в активити. Через putExtra могу передать данные, но не очень понятно, как потом вернуть этот массив. startActivityForResult не совсем то, что мне нужно, потому что он возвращает данные только в предыдущий класс, а у меня должна быть возможность перейти в другие активити, помимо домашнего экрана, да и если нажать кнопку Back, то результат не передается. Что можно сделать в данном случае?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final boolean[] fStars = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l1);
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Block1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Привел пример. Массив булов как-то должен стать доступен другим классам не только для чтения, но и для редактирования.

Comment: Используйте SharedPreferenses

Comment: Если вы передаете массив через extra то нет необходимости его ловить в onActivityResult так как он передается по ссылке

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо!